# Transient time of a circuit and pulse width

Tags: pulse, transient

I'm taking a course on Analog and Digital Circuits, and in the course material, in a passage regarding pulse signals, I found the following statement:

> Relation between the transitory regime of a circuit and the pulse signal
>
> - Any state switch of a circuit implies generation of a transitory regime, taking a bounded time
> - **For a pulse signal, the swing times between levels must be lower or comparable with the period of the transitory regime**
> - For a pulse the repetition period T must be much greater than the duration of the transitory regime

(emphasis mine)

But I didn't understand why the second one would that matter for a simple diode, which was used as an example.

[image]

Comment: Huh?  What is *this* circuit?  How can you possibly imagine that we can tell what the rise time requirements are of a circuit you haven't given us any information on.  We do engineering here, not hand waving.

Comment: I don't know @OlinLathrop, engineering is pretty hand-wavey sometimes! Ever had to choose a resistor value between 1k and 100k? lol

Comment: The example was a simple diode, but this "principle" was stated as a general rule.

Comment: I've put the relevant part of the course material in the question, you're free to edit or rollback of course. But I didn't see anywhere mention of a diode, and I don't see where it would logically fit. Also note that it's better to wait before accepting an answer, as it will generally discourage people from answering.

Comment: The example was given at the blackboard, explaing exactly what shouldn't be done, but not why it shouldn't be done.

Comment: A diode sitting on a table has no inputs and output. What is the diode you're asking about connected to?

Comment: The diode was just an example. This "rule" should be applied to any pulse signal feeding any circuit. I will ask the professor what he meant by that to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

What the statement means is that in order to have a pulse signal, the interval between edges must be comparable or larger than the duration of the transients. Otherwise the circuit won't have enough time to complete the voltage swing between the logical levels, and will be predominantly in the transient phase, resulting in meta-stability or unstability.

If you think about it, if it takes 100ms to change level and the pulse only lasts 1ms, it will be filtered out and won't result in a clear waveform.

Comment: I understand why the period of the input signal has to be considerably larger than the "reaction speed", but the question was why should the "rising time" of the input be smaller than this "reaction speed".

Comment: This was my first ever course regarding electronics, even though I studied some notions by myself. The exact statement in the course is: "For a pulse signal, the swing times between levels must be lower or comparable with the period of the transitory regime". But I didn't understand why would that matter for a simple diode, which was used as an example.

Comment: @user42768 without the context I can't make sense of that statement. But then I don't think it applies to what I said in my answer, it's more about the signal itself. It's good if you put it in the question.

Comment: I fully understand the third condition, the second one is my problem.

Comment: @user sorry I got confused.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I understand of the text:

> Any state switch of a circuit implies generation of a transitory regime, taking a bounded time

This is typical of circuits containing elements that *store energy*. Switching between two states of the excitation source, implies a change in the energy of the circuit, this variation **should occur continuously**. For an **inductor**, *the current* passing through it, must vary continuously. In the case of a **capacitor**, the *applied voltage* should vary continuously. These continuity requirements imply that *it can not reach the new state of energy in a range from zero time*, but that requires some time (transient) for the circuit to reach a new steady state energy.

> For a pulse signal, the swing times between levels must be lower or comparable with the period of the transitory regime

This is directly related to the above interpretation. Since the time between two stable states of energy *is characteristic of the system* (and not of the source), *pulsed excitation signal should not repeat their pulses within a shorter time interval at which the system can respond*.
Normally, once known the time constant of the system, it is considered that the steady state has been reached in a time interval equal to **five times the time constant**. If the signal repeats its pulse excitation before this time, you will find the system *still in transient response*. Maybe the system will respond to this signal by filtering (in the case of passive networks), or your system may become totally unstable at this excitation, which can lead to destruction.
If the pulse excitation signal is repeated with an interval of time such that the system found steady state between pulses, there will be major effects than filtering.

What relevance does this with a [**diode**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%E2%80%93n_diode)? Well, although the diode is a nonlinear element, presents behaviors that can be modeled with components that store energy as [diffusion capacitance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_capacitance) and others. As you increase the frequency of the processed signal (period decreases) by the diode, these transient effects become more evident.

> For a pulse the repetition period T must be much greater than the duration of the transitory regime

This was interpreted in the previous paragraph.

Comment: I edited my post to show what was meant by that statement.

Comment: @user42768 I have added a little explanatory paragraph about the diode.

Answer (score 0):

Point 2 seems to be the nub of the question.

**For a pulse signal, the swing times between levels must be lower or comparable with the period of the transitory regime**

Swing times == rise and fall times

period of the transistory regime (who wrote this drivel?) === pulse width

**Translation:**

If the rise and fall times > pulse width the pulse will not be formed and will lead to error.

**Picture it:**

[image]

All components exhibit to some degree **capacitive** and **inductive** traits.  It the pulses are very short or these effects are significant at that frequency the pulse may not get through the device (even a diode!).

Comment: I think swing time is a property of the signal (rise or fall) and period of transitory regime refers to the time it takes a circuit driven by a perfect input signal to change from LOW to HIGH. I will ask the professor and post his answer if it is satisfactory.